# Is there any plugin which can convert all types of font files to base64 using gulp npm

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am new to npm and gulp I found cssfont64 which can convert .ttf files to base64, but I would like convert all types of font files to base64, .eot, .woff, .ttf.

I tried using base64 pack but it not converting all.

can anyone suggest any npm plugin.

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/jalkoby/gulp-inline-fonts

Answer (score 1):

`gulp-inline-fonts` can do this (you'll need to set the `format` option). https://github.com/jalkoby/gulp-inline-fonts